# How to deploy a packaged custom policy on mule4.x runtime environment without using any point platform version 2

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform

On Linux we have the MULE_HOME/policies directory. We are trying to deploy manually the packaged policy as per documentation from  [mule documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/policies-custom-landing-page)

We don't want to use any point platform. Any idea or any documentation there 
We used to drop different mule jar (application jar and domain jar) into apps and domains folder and it works fine( hot deploy).
This is for mule runtime version 4.2.x
Please notice, if anybody, the custom policy has to be connected to the exposed API or the mule application under the apps folder.  In summary, to do the manual job as it is done from the GUI by anypoint platform

Comment: What's the reason for not using Anypoint Platform to manage the policies?

Comment: @aled  can it be done or not ?

Comment: To improve the quality of the question is better to provide more context in the form of requirements and restrictions. Any answers should be provided in the answers section below.